# TextView widget cannot be resolved

Tags: android, textview, widget

I have created a blank activity project in Android Studio choosing API 14 (4.0 ICS) as the Minimum SDK.

​In the main activity I assigned an id to the default 'hello world' TextView​ as below

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hw_1"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

​I then tried to change the default 'Hello world' message programmatically ​by doing

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hw_1);
    tv.setText("my new message");
```

However, I keep getting 'cannot resolve symbol TextView' and when trying to import I just do not see the TextView in the list of the widgets under `android.widget` package as depicted in the image below.

I am just starting Android and thinking that I might be missing something obvious but can't figure out what exactly cause I do see TextView inside the Android jar linked to the project etc.

**Check the image below.**

[image]

Comment: chk for u hv proper project properties

Comment: Which properties!? This is a fresh project with nothing in it. Just the main activity and the layout and as seen from the picture other widgets are in place.

Comment: ypu but there must be android api selected for the same just google once

Comment: yea, why did not I think of googling before posting this question ...

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Yes, with no success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone runs into this.

I figured there should be something on the IDE level and decided to check out how IntelliJ decides what to show in the import popup. After few minutes of digging I found the "Exclude from Import and Completion" section under IDE Settings -> Editor and there it was - the TextView import was explicitly excluded from import and completion suggestoins. 
Not sure how it got there in the first place, but oh well ..